# Git repository references code from another git repository

Tags: git, github

Repository A has a custom form navigation engine that we wrote (just as an example), as well as a lot of other code.  Repository B will be a separate project that wants to use the same form navigation engine.  We don't want to keep copies of the code in two places, we just want commits in Repo A to be seen by the project in Repo B.  Is this a case for submodules in Git?  If not, what is the recommended method to reference code from another repo?  thanks

Comment: use submodules or subtrees: http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both submodules and subtree merges are for this scenario. I'd go for subtrees, as submodules are a royal PITA. See @three's link in the question's comments. Excellent read.

Upon popular request: Why submodules are a royal PITA

- For many years there was no command to remove a submodule. Is there any yet?
- Redundant storage of submodule URLs in 3 places: main project .gitmodules, main project config, submodule config
- Resulting need to `submodule update` all the time
- Simple checkout operations become nightmares, especially when one branch has the submodule, but the other not
- People assume there is a recursive push, but there cannot be, as submodules might come from read-only URLs
- But forgot to push submodule before main repo? Public main repo broken.

All of the above problems disappear with subtree merges. The price: pushing to subproject's upstream is non-trivial.

Comment: See update. Result of developers working with submodules regularly. Not without any problems.

Comment: subtree merging did the trick, thanks!  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/562950/GitplusSubtreeplusMergeplus-e-TheplusQuickpl